# Html.RenderPartial & Multiple controls with same id error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, renderpartial

I have made myself a small user control for consuming a feed, the code for said user control looks like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SyndicationFeed >" %>

<%foreach (var rss in ViewData.Model.Items)
  {
      Response.Write("<div id={0}><a href={1} target=\"_blank\" /> <strong>{2}</strong></div>", 
          rss.Links[0].Uri.OriginalString, rss.Title.Text, rss.Title.Text);
      Response.Write("<div>" + rss.Summary.Text.Truncate(100) + "</div>")
  }%>
```

The code for the RssController looks like this

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    string feedUrl = @"http://wdfw.wa.gov/news/newsrss.php";

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUrl))
    {
        SyndicationFeed rss = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        return View(rss);
    }            
}
```

And I call it in Site.Master like so

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("Index", Model);%>
```

I've also tried

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("Index", ViewData.Model);%>
```

All resulting in this this error:

> Multiple controls with the same ID
>   'ctl00' were found. Trace requires
>   that controls have unique IDs.

Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use Html.RenderAction("Index","Rss") instead Html.RederPartial? When Html.RenderAction is called by ViewEngine, all code in your Index action is executed and Model with rss data goes to Index view to be generated to markup. And why do you use Response.Write, in view you can put html tags and this markup will be inserted where you are calling Html.RenderAction. Hope it will be helpful for you, if not, sorry, at least I've tried ))

Best regards,
Dima.

Comment: Dim I tried your option and I get this message Compiler Error Message: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewExtensions.RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)'

Comment: @PsychoCoder it isn't correct as I can see from your comment.. why did you mark it as answer??